# Why am I having issues indexing a list in Elisp?

Tags: lisp, elisp

I've been playing around with ELisp and have come up again a weird bug in my code

The error I'm getting is:

```
  Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Bad bounding indices: 2, 3")
  signal(error ("Bad bounding indices: 2, 3"))
  error("%s" "Bad bounding indices: 2, 3")
  subseq((quote (2 2 2 2)) 2 3)
  (matrix-from-values 1 number-of-columns-on-output (subseq (nth 2 matrix) (+ (* row-index number-of-columns-on-input) start-column) (+ (* row-index number-of-columns-on-input) end-column)))
  (let ((number-of-columns-on-input (nth 1 matrix)) (number-of-columns-on-output (- end-column start-column)) (row-index (- row 1))) (matrix-from-values 1 number-of-columns-on-output (subseq (nth 2 matrix) (+ (* row-index number-of-columns-on-input) start-column) (+ (* row-index number-of-columns-on-input) end-column))))
  matrix-extract-subrow((2 2 (quote (2 2 2 2))) 1 2 3)
  [..more stuff..]
```

It's likely I'm not reading the error correctly, but as I understand it the interpreter evaluates my function (the "(matrix..[blah-blah]" thing) from the inside out and trips up on:

```
  subseq((quote (2 2 2 2)) 2 3)
```

However if I go into the *scratch* buffer and run:

```
(subseq (quote (2 2 2 2)) 2 3)
```

It runs just fine

Comment: Note that `subseq((quote (2 2 2 2)) 2 3)` is not one form, but two. You have the variable `subseq` and then a function call where the function is the evaluation of `(quote (2 2 2 2))` and the two arguments `2` and `3`. I doubt evaluating `(quote (2 2 2 2))` will give you a callable function. `(subseq (quote (2 2 2 2)) 2 3)` is one form calling the function `subseq` with a list an dtwo numeric arguments.

Comment: Thanks - That explains why the error is talking about the arguments. It's misleading at first blush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing *values* and *expressions*.  In source code you write expressions, whereas in the above debugger output you see values.  `eval` takes an expression and returns the corresponding value, while `quote` can be used to take a value and turn it back into a (trivial) expression which just returns that value.

So when you see `subseq((quote (2 2 2 2)) 2 3)` it means `subseq` was called with a value `(quote (2 2 2 2))`, which you get for example by evaluating an expression like `(quote (quote (2 2 2 2)))`.

You stripped the rest of the backtrace, but looking at

```
matrix-extract-subrow((2 2 (quote (2 2 2 2))) 1 2 3)
```

it seems like maybe you have somewhere something like

```
... '(2 2 '(2 2 2 2)) ...
```

which should really be

```
... '(2 2 (2 2 2 2)) ..
```

instead.

Comment: That was very observant of you! Thank you for pointing out the issue. Next time I'll include the whole trace (I initially didn't think it was relevant here)

Could you explain why the second quote isn't necessary?
I was concerned it would try to evaluate the inner expression. Does the outer quote essentially ensure everything inside is interpreted as-is already?

Comment: Within a quote you're inside a value, i.e. "data", so nothing gets evaluated because it's already evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra layer of quoting somewhere.  I can reproduce your error if I evaluate

```
(subseq (quote (quote (2 2 2 2))) 2 3)
```

Without seeing the actual elisp code you are running, and how you are calling it when it errors, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. You were correct. I must misunderstand how quotes are used a bit. I'll make sure to include the whole trace next time. I was trying to make it easier but ended up making the problem harder to figure out